# Can Runnable be used for non-thread related things?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, functional-interface

I am curious, can we use the functional interface `Runnable` also for non-thread related purposes?

I see it only being used by classes like `Thread`, `ExecutorService` and similar, for thread-related topics. And its [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) also only states thread-related usages.

---

What would be the impact of using it as *normal* functional interface instead of creating my own functional interface to represent `void _()` (no output, no input)?

Would it maybe start creating new threads or do other funky stuff? Would it be confusing for other developers or is it common practice?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) clearly states that the `Runnable` interface is all about threads.  Using the interface in a way that is contrary to the documentation would violate the "Principle of Least Surprise."

Comment: Well, you will always have at least one thread executing (the main thread). If you execute a runnable, you need a thread. (It doesn't have to be a new or different thread) … :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, I disagree.  Runnable is widely used as a generic "task" interface, separate from threads, and when we designed the functional interfaces in Java 8, we explicitly did not create another functional interface to match the shape of Runnable.  Using Runnable in this way is 100% acceptable and reasonable.   It might be reasonable to update the documentation for Runnable (since it probably hasn't been updated since Java 1.0), but the OP should feel perfectly good about using Runnable in this way.

Comment: @BrianGoetz: How soon can we get the documentation fixed? :)

Comment: `Runnable` literally is _just_ an `interface`. There's no magic. You can use it the same way you would use any other interface. That is, assuming you need an interface that declares a method named `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

No (runtime) impact at all. Runnable is a SAM type with a method `run()`.

Developers who already know the Runnable interface immediately know what type your code expects. If you introduce a new, custom type, developers will first have to read and understand your documentation.

SAM types with compatible interface can easily be converted to one another:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyRunnable {
  void myRun();
}

class MyClass {
  public static doWork(Runnable runnable) {
    runnable.run();
  }
  public static doMyWork(MyRunnable myRunnable) {
    myRunnable.myRun();
  }

  public static void main() {
    Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("run");
    MyRunnable myRunnable = () -> System.out.println("my run");
    doWork(runnable);
    doWork(myRunnable::myRun); // doWork(() -> myRunnable.myRun());
    doMyWork(runnable::run); // doMyWork(() -> runnable.run());
    doMyWork(myRunnable);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was actually surprised to see, when reading the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) (even recent versions), that it only mentions thread usage. Which is interesting, since iirc I have also seen it being used for non-thread related things even within the JDK (as substitute for a functional interface with signature `void foo()`).

Comment: @Zabuzard The Runnable docs probably haven't been updated since Java 1.0, and reflect the initial reason it was added to the JDK.   Over time, it has found other uses.

Answer (score 0):

### Impact

You will not see any negative effect at all. Its `run()` method does not create threads or anything like that, neither does it do anything else than what you tell it to do.

So a usage like

```java
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello World!");

runnable.run(); // Hello World!
```

Does work perfectly fine, with no unwanted side effects.

`Runnable` is in fact also used for such non-thread related stuff already at many places, also within the JDK itself.

---

### Javadoc

Reading its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html), it appears that the interface is **only meant** to be used **for thread related** things.

So you might think that you will trip other developers if you *abuse* it for other things.

However, reading **Brian Goetz** comment, it appears that this is rather an oversight and the Javadoc was just forgotten to be adjusted when `Runnable` started being used for other things with Java 8 onwards as well.

It is likely that the Javadoc will *soon* get adjusted and a non-thread related usage is then compliant with the documentation as well.

---

### Alternative

That said, if you need a functional interface for a signature like `void _()`, i.e.

- no output
- no input
- just execute some code

It is also fair if you rather want to create your own functional interface, in which case you have an **opportunity** to also give it a **more appropriate domain-specific name**. For example:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CleanupTask {
  void cleanup();
}
```

```java
CleanupTask task = () -> System.out.println("Cleaning up...");

task.cleanup(); // Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Note that [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) already exists as a well-known interface in the `java.util.concurrent` package. It is a SAM type too and has a single method `execute(Runnable)`. So creating an interface with identical name but different methods/behavior would be even more confusing :)